# application stopped on android phone

Tags: android, eclipse, windows, unity-game-engine, apk

I create a simple AR application using unity. It works on windows pc using unity. To run on a android phone, I did below steps :

On unity

1. Click file->build settings->android, select google android project and press build button.

On phone

1. I click usb debugging, allow mock location

On eclipse

1. import project and select the android project that I create on unity.
2. Copy android project apk file to phone
3. Click project name, right click, run as android application.

On phone, app says that xxx stopped. I press debug as android application, there is no extra message on console. What can I do?

I can run a hello world example on phone.

Comment: **"What can I do?"** Post your code and also the logcat showing the stacktrace for when the app stops.

Answer (score 0):

you can deploy to android directly from Unity if you install the Android SDK along with the google usb drivers and set it from Edit->Preferences->External tools.

Comment: Should I install Android SDK on the phone?

Comment: I install sdk to pc, I export android project from unity. And I copy apk file to the phone. I install my app on phone, but it was stooped.

Comment: Like I said you can deploy directly to the phone from Unity if you link the android SDK you have on your computer in the unity editor. There is no need to install the SDK on the phone , to be honest I dont think you even can.

Answer (score 0):

you can export an apk file directly from unity but first time you want to do it you have to give the address of your android sdk. if you do it right it will give you the apk file.

there are something that you have to know. current unity version just give an export for arm7 processor phones. 
you have to know about minimum version that you get export. some features dont work on lower versions.

Comment: I don't use eclipse now. I click build and run on unity. it works fine. Thanx your answer.